# representing strings as features in decision trees with vocabulary size of 200(with or without one-hot encoding)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm new to Machine learning!

I tried to label encode my entire vocabulary in sci-kit learn. But when the decision-tree was generated, the comparison was in the form of float type.
(eg: type <= 9.5 ) which doesn't make any sense. 
So I decided to One-hot encode my labels.But the columns which have vocabulary size 200 was repeated more than once(5 to be precise) in my data-set. The no of columns for each data was huge(5*200 + 3).So that didn't seem to be a proper solution. My vocabulary consists of a list of function names in javascript.
Are there any other ways to represent these strings as features in a decision tree or should I use any other model??

Update on my question: 
My data looks like this:

The columns are:

Input Features

column1: string ( Can be any word from the vocabulary of size 200. Note: These are function call names so this is analogous to color names or country names)

Likewise, there are 4 similar columns like column1.

Output Feature(Label):

String type. This can any word from a vocabulary of size 500. Again these are function call names so this is analogous to color names or country names)

Comment: I think using `CountVectorizer` is the best option here. Sharing some input data might help us be more specific

Comment: I suggest you to use tf-idf vectorizer, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Comment: @MohamedThasinah isn't tf-idf used for document comparison? Here my javascript function names are given as features ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the countVectorizer for this, even when your input is not documents.

Consider for example your vocabulary of javascript functions as `vocab_functions`. Your input functions be present in five columns of a dataframe as follows

```
df[func1],df[func2],df[func3],df[func4],df[func5]
```

Join all the function names with space inbetween to form a new column

```
df['input_func']
```

Now apply the countVectorizer on this column,

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'func_asb func_asdnl func_15 func_sx funcd3d',
    'func_11 func_sav3 func_fdasvb15 func_saax funcdnlvasdd',
]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()#add --- vocabulary=vocab_functions

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus) # replace with df['input_func']

X.todense()
#
matrix([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Feed this X to decision tree, which would be of dimension 200.

Comment: Concat all five function call names into a string and feed it to countVectorizer()